# Replicate Postgres to Cockroach

Tags: replication, postgresql-9.6, cockroachdb

We are planning to replicate our Postgres database to Cockroach. We are looking for a relatively simpler solution to achieve that.

Currently, we are working on a Stream based replication (something of [this](https://github.com/jensneuse/PostgresLogicalReplicationExample) sort) is there any better alternative than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CockroachDB PM here. I don't have a very satisfying answer for you, unfortunately; Postgres logical decoding is difficult to implement correctly, and I don't know of anything offhand that satisfies your needs.

Postgres links to a number of [off-the-shelf logical decoding plugins](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logical_Decoding_Plugins), but in my experience these are of varying quality. If you use one of these, you'll want to verify that it properly handles columns that use Postgres's [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/storage-toast.html) mechanism -- last time I looked at these, they generally did not. After you get your data streaming out of Postgres, you can consume them and upsert them into your Cockroach database on a separate SQL connection.

If a zero-downtime migration is not required, you could use CockroachDB's [`IMPORT PGDUMP`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v2.2/migrate-from-postgres.html) functionality: use Postgres's own dump functionality to dump your data to a file, and then import it into CockroachDB.